# Elastalert creating index not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I'm installing elastalert in my local installation of ELK. When I run the command 'elastalert-create-index' I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\elastalert-create-index-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('elastalert==0.1.8', 'console_scripts', 'elastalert-create-index')()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\elastalert\create_index.py", line 83, in main
    profile_name=args.profile)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\elastalert\auth.py", line 24, in __call__
    aws_access_key=credentials.access_key,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access_key'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue, fixed by editing config.yaml, setting host/port there and uncommenting es_username & es_password.

Our ES instance is local and not password protected. Still worked with the default username & password (ignores it I guess).

Not a fix, but a workaround.

Comment: Was issue raised in github.com it's resolved now. It was due to considering every elasticsearch as located in cloud. You can comment out the line calling for aw keys in the code and compile/install it again

Answer (score 0):

This could occur due to a number of possible reasons.

1. elasticsearch might not be running
   If not, start elasticsearch
2. The elastalert version might not be compatible with elasticsearch.
   The version of elastalert and elasticsearch should be same or atleast close. Ex: If elasticsearch version is 5.0.0 then elastalert version should also be 5.0.0 or something close to it.
3. Ensure that the host and port specified in config.yaml are correct.
4. Check if access key is specified properly.

Comment: it's not possible, ES current version is 7.8.0, elastalert latest is 0.2.4